# How is DEX comparable in performance to neo4j?

Tags: graph, graph-databases

Reading through the internals of DEX and how it is using BITMAP indexes to support OLAP kinda queries it definitely seems superior to other techniques. Does anyone has practical experience comparing it against NEO4J, TITAN, etc.